# Powershell New-SmbMapping drives only accessible from Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, powershell-3.0, smb

As I understand it, `New-SmbMapping W: -RemotePath \\myserver\myfolder` should do the same thing as `net use w: \\myserver\myfolder`.  However, if I use `net` I am easily able to access the mapped drive from the Windows Explorer.  On the other hand, if I use `New-SmbMapping`, it shows up if I run `Get-SmbMapping`, and I can access it with the `start W:` command, but it doesn't show up in My Computer and if I type W: into the Windows Explorer bar Windows complains about being unable to find the file location.  What's wrong here?

Comment: This question probably belongs on superuser instead of here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `New-SmbMaping` but in PowerShell 3.0 you can use the New-PSdrive and the -Persist switch to map a drive. Remoce the psdrive to disconnect from the mapped network drive.

```
New-PSDrive -Name W -Root \\myserver\myfolder -Persist -PSProvider FileSystem
```

Comment: Well, I'll be damned, that works.  Thanks.